# Optimal solution for looping and inserting/updating

Tags: sql-server

I am interested to know if there is a better / more optimal solution than what I have so far as it uses a cursor, which I know is not too good performance wise.

Basically my requirement is too check if a number of settings exists for an ID and then update or insert them accordingly.

To do this I have:

```
DECLARE @UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = '{PUT-GUID-HERE}'
```

I then declare a table variable which I add the setting names and values to, there are approx 15 of these in total.

```
DECLARE @SettingsToCheck TABLE (SettingName varchar(100), SettingValue varchar(100)
INSERT INTO @SettingsToCheck ('Setting1', 'Setting1 Value') --Repeat...

DECLARE @CurrentSettingName varchar(100)
DECLARE @CurrentSettingValue varchar(100)
DECLARE Settings_Cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT SettingName, SettingValue FROM @SettingsToCheck
OPEN Settings_Cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM Settings_Cursor INTO @CurrentSettingName, @CurrentSettingValue
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MyActualTable WHERE UserID = @UserId AND SettingName = @CurrentSettingName)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE MyActualTable SET SettingValue = @CurrentSettingValue WHERE UserID = @UserId AND SettingName = @CurrentSettingName
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO MyActualTableVALUES (NEWID(), @UserId, GETDATE(), @CurrentSettingName, @CurrentSettingValue)
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM Settings_Cursor INTO @CurrentSettingName, @CurrentSettingValue
END

CLOSE Settings_Cursor
DEALLOCATE Settings_Cursor
```

I know this question is subject to opinion, but I am unaware of any alternatives.

**EDIT:**

There could be a scenario where some/none or all of the settings already exist. But here's an example.

**BEFORE:**

```
SettingName  |  SettingValue
____________________________
Setting1     |  Setting1Value
```

**AFTER:**

```
SettingName  |  SettingValue
____________________________
Setting1     |  Setting1ValueUPDATED

Setting2     |  NewSetting
```

Comment: Not looping would be the first step; you're writing SQL not C#. Set-based methods will almost always out perform a loop in SQL (there are some very few occasions this isn't true, so as "set-based loops"). Sample data, and expected results would help here greatly.

Comment: I could just repeat the IF EXISTS block for 15 or so settings, but this would become quite unreadable, but happy to make the sacrifice if required. The code work fine so the expected results are just updated values in the table.

Comment: Not sure that would make it more performant either; I can't see your design, but i suspect you'd be able to do this in a single statement. Impossible to suggest more without sample data and expected results.

Comment: I have updated my question with a very basic before/after example. Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Merge as below

```
DECLARE @SettingsToCheck TABLE 
(
    SettingName varchar(100)
    ,SettingValue varchar(100)
)

DECLARE @ActualTable TABLE 
(
    SettingName varchar(100)
    ,SettingValue varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @SettingsToCheck 
VALUES
('Setting1', 'Setting1 Value') --Repeat...
,('Setting2', 'Setting2 Value') 
,('Setting3', 'Setting3 Value') 
,('Setting4', 'Setting45 Value') 
,('Setting5', 'Setting5 Value') 
,('Setting6', 'Setting6 Value') 
,('Setting7', 'Setting7 Value') 


INSERT INTO @ActualTable 
VALUES
 ('Setting4', 'Setting4 Value')

MERGE INTO @ActualTable  AS target
USING @SettingsToCheck AS source
    ON target.SettingName = source.SettingName
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET target.SettingValue = source.SettingValue
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (SettingName, SettingValue)
    VALUES (source.SettingName, source.SettingValue);

Select * from @ActualTable
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try this afternoon.

Comment: I have used SettingName for identification of record. You can add the UserId in that condition. let me know about any feedback...

Answer (score 0):

I know people like to use MERGE, but I prefer just separating them out to their individual task.  Aaron Bertrand documented some of the issues with MERGE here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/,
but I am not sure how many of those still persist.

Anyways, this is an alternative:

```
CREATE TABLE #SettingsToCheck 
(
    SettingName varchar(100)
    ,SettingValue varchar(100)
)


CREATE TABLE #ActualTable 
(
    SettingName varchar(100)
    ,SettingValue varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO #SettingsToCheck 
VALUES
('Setting1', 'Setting1 Value') --Repeat...
,('Setting2', 'Setting2 Value') 
,('Setting3', 'Setting3 Value') 
,('Setting4', 'Setting45 Value') 
,('Setting5', 'Setting5 Value') 
,('Setting6', 'Setting6 Value') 
,('Setting7', 'Setting7 Value') 


INSERT INTO #ActualTable 
VALUES
 ('Setting4', 'Setting4 Value')


 UPDATE #ActualTable 
    SET SettingValue = t2.SettingValue
    FROM #ActualTable t1
    INNER JOIN #SettingsToCheck t2 on t1.SettingName = t2.SettingName

INSERT INTO #ActualTable(SettingName,SettingValue)
SELECT t1.SettingName,t1.SettingValue   
    FROM #SettingsToCheck t1
    LEFT JOIN #ActualTable t2 on t1.SettingName = t2.SettingName
    WHERE t2.SettingName IS NULL

select * from #ActualTable
```